# where is the center of rotation of GetAngle() method

Tags: box2d

In Box2d, where is the center of rotation when we achieve the angle by using GetAngle method? is it the center of mass, the center of AABB or somewhere else?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no center of rotation, there is only the angle. As an analogy, if you park your car facing northwest, what is the center of rotation of the car?

The only time there is something that might be called a center of rotation is when you use ApplyTorque to turn a body. In that case the torque will be applied about the center of mass.